# jpcap.dll on a 64 bit system?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, jpcap

Hey i was using the Jpcap API on my system. It requires you to put a copy of jpcap.dll in the system32 folder. The problem is that it doesnt work on my 64 bit system.

I tried running a program in eclipse n it gave the following error -

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\jpcap.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform "

Is there a 64bit version of Jpcap.dll or how do i convert it or run on a 64 bit machine ?

Answer (score 3):

Even I don't know why this problem actually arises but I solved this problem by installing a `32-bit JDK` rather than a `64-bit` and it works absolutely fine.

You can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

friends you can use the 64 bit jpcap .dll file from following link [jpcap .dll for win 64](https://github.com/jovigb/jpcap-x64/blob/master/lib/Jpcapx64.dll) . Just rename it as jpcap.dll and use it...

Answer (score 0):

There is another library, [jnetpcap](http://jnetpcap.com/download), that has both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows versions.  I don't know whether the API is in any way compatible with Jpcap, but if there is a dying need to use WinPCap through Java on Windows x64 this might be an option.

This library also seems to be more maintained than Jpcap.  Jpcap's last update according to [it's main website](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) is 2007, jnetpcap has had updates this year (as of 2012-11-09).